# Two State Implicit Filter Derivation

Tags: kalman-filter, robotics, schur-complement

I've been reading The ["Two-State Implicit Filter – Recursive Estimation for Mobile Robots" by Bloesch](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/242919/bloesch2018ral.pdf?sequence=1). The gist of the paper is it tries to find the balance between a Kalman Filter and a Batch optimizer for robotics applications, and introduces a Two State Implicit Filter. Essentially a sliding window estimator of size 2.

The system of equations given (Eq (25) in the paper) to solve for states $x^{k}_{k - 1}$ and $x^{k}_{k}$ are given as:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    P^{-1}_{k-1} + A^{T} A & A^{T} B \\
    B^{T} A & B^{T} B
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x^{k}_{k - 1} \\
    x^{k}_{k} 
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    P^{-1}_{k-1} x^{k-1}_{k-1} - A^{T} b_{k} \\
    -B^{T} b_k
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Then the author uses the Schur complement to marginalize the previous state $x^{k}_{k-1}$, since we are only interested in obtaining the latest state $x^{k}_{k}$. What I do not understand is how the author managed to go from:

\begin{equation}
  P^{-1}_{k} x^{k}_{k} = B^{T} (A(P^{-1}_{k-1} + A^{T} A)^{-1} (A^{T} b_k - P^{-1}_{k-1} x^{k-1}_{k-1}) - b_k)
\end{equation}

to:

\begin{equation}
  P^{-1}_{k} x^{k}_{k} = -B^{T} (I - A(P^{-1}_{k-1} + A^{T} A)^{-1} A^{T}) (A x^{k-1}_{k-1} + b_k)
\end{equation}

In Eq (27) of the paper. Apologies if this is just a simple rearranging of terms, but I just don't see it.

Comment: I don't see it either. I suspect there might be a typo, or they made a substitution going between those lines. In your position, I would suggest making sure that you agree with how they got the first line of Eq (27) and then look for typos or substitutions that might explain the next step.

Comment: Not too sure its a typo. There's a C++ implementation of it, and the implementation seems to match Eq. (28 - 31) here: https://github.com/ethz-asl/two_state_information_filter/blob/e754abdd8ee41c599e55185cd1a5e84ee4238b1a/include/tsif/filter.h#L197

Additionally, the Two State Implicit Filter (TSIF) has been used other papers as a form of comparison: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.07243v1)%3C%22

Comment: Their math in the C++ library is probably correct, but it's pretty common to accidentally introduce errors when typing things up.